# Index was outside the bounds of the array vb.net meaning

Tags: arrays, vb.net, exception

I'm still a beginner in VB and an error occur "Index was outside the bounds of the array". What does that mean?

This is part of my code:

```
spectraldata.Text = "Area: " & dt.Rows(0)("area").ToString & 
    vbCrLf & "Laptitude: " & dt.Rows(0).Item("laptitude").ToString & 
    "Longtitude: " & dt.Rows(0)("longtitude").ToString & 
    "Field View: " & dt.Rows(0).Item("field_view").ToString & 
    vbCrLf & "Date Collected: " & 
    dt.Rows(0).Item("date_collected").ToString & "Start Time: " & 
    dt.Rows(0).Item("start_time").ToString & "End Time: " & 
    dt.Rows(0).Item("end_time").ToString & "Sky Status: " & 
    dt.Rows(0).Item("sky_status").ToString & "Name Of Person: " & 
    dt.Rows(0).Item("name_person").ToString
```

Kindly explain and how can I fix it.

[This is part of my code:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vIFR3.png)

I have tried the query in sql server and it gave me a result.

Comment: That means, the index, you wanted to access, is outside of the array bounds. Ref. https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.array(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: You'll need to show some code and we can point out where you are going wrong. This is also a common error so you might want to search around. Have a look at [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to see how to ask a good question.

Comment: The exception tells you that you have tried to access an item in an array at an invalid index. An array (or list) indexer always starts with 0 (not 1) and ends with `array.Length -1`. So the last item in an array is `array(array.Length-)` and not `array(array.Length)`.

Comment: Change `dt.Rows(0)("longtitude").ToString` to `dt.Rows(0).Item("longtitude").ToString` and `dt.Rows(0)("area")` to `dt.Rows(0).Item("area")`

Comment: I did and still an error.

Comment: Just a thought - Are the column names correctly spelt? laptitude and longtitude are normally spelt latitude and longitude

Comment: Another thought: just for debugging, concatenate the string in seperate lines, for each item in the row one line, not in one single line.

Comment: another thought, just access one column at a time, remove other columns from the code and check from sql server side as well that its value in not null then check from your app code.

Comment: all the names are correct, and I did put every string in a separate line, still error! should I write "for each i as datarow in dt.rows" etc..??

Comment: @davidWilson  the spelling is correct

Answer (score 0):

Quite simply, you have tried to access an element greater than the size of the items in the list.

e.g. If you have 4 items in a list and you ask for the 5th item. It isn't possible as it doesn't exist, thats all the exception means.

Looking at your example I would say that you don't have anything in dt.Rows(0), i.e. there are not actually any results here.

Comment: _"greater than the size"_  or  
index is less than zero.

Comment: actually when I put the query in my sql server, it did gave me a result but only 1 row.

Comment: Are you certain the exception is thrown on those lines? You only look to reference Rows(0) above, so if there is actually a result it should work,

Comment: When I debugged the code, dt.Rows.count = 1 so there is a row. but I don't where is the error??